# Shimano cleats, Exustar shoes: Which bolts to use?

Tags: shoes

I just got Exustar shoes and Shimano SPD-SL pedals with SM-SH11 cleats. Problem is, the cleat fixing bolts that were included with the cleats aren't long enough to bolt to the shoes. I'm wondering what length of bolt will work best for this? I'm seeing a lot of "extra long 13.5mm bolts" online- would they be long enough to bolt to Exustar shoes?

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: You could take everything to a hardware store and find a suitable fit.  Even if they don't have the exactly correct pan head screws you can find something close enough to figure out what would fit.

Comment: They're standard M5 bolts, I believe, you should be able to find them almost anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Measure to make sure they are long enough. If they are too long, screw a nut on then cut it with a metal saw at the right length. Use a file to make it smooth then unscrew the nut to make sure the threads are nice and clean.

Comment: You mean, "screw a *nut* on.  (Though sawing off such a short bolt would be a challenge.)

Comment: If the bolt's a bit short and thin, I've used boltcutters to trim the end, and then thread-off the sacrificial nut that was threadded in first.